# $_REQUEST php equivalent in node js

Tags: php, node.js

Actually I am using a third party api url of Plivo.
There I need to supply a URL with POST method on which they are gonna post call data .

I have provided url in lumen and able to get the data posted by third party url using $_REQUEST successfully.

Now I am trying implement the same in node js express like:

```
exports.plivoIvrCallback = function (req, res) {
   console.log(req);
}
```

but I am not getting anything in req or req.body !

So what might be node js equivalent to $_REQUEST in php.??

Answer (score 0):

Please install [body-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser) package and then try.

Comment: I ave already installed bodyParser. Now how to use it to get desired result?

Answer (score 0):

you can install `body-parser` (as suggested by @ Mr.Gandhi) or any other requests parsers you want, than add the following line at the start of your handler:

```
let request = Object.assign(req.query, req.body); // you can also add here req.params etc...
```

and use `request` from now on.

Comment: So if the parameter name you were looking for was `urmom`, how do you reference it? `request.urmom`?